# Reasons behind std::discrete_distribution interface

Tags: algorithm, c++11, stl, random

According to cppreference.com `std::discrete_distribution` interface requires library developers to implement `probabilities()` and `template<class Generator> result_type operator()(Generator& g, const param_type& params);`. The latter is not documented on cppreference.com, but according to [libc++ implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/random) it allows user to sample from subsequence of given sequence of weights (and use passed generator as source of entropy for another generator, but it's irrelevant now). I've read [N3551](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3551.pdf) (the only googleable proposal about `std::discrete_distribution`) and it's doesn't provide any reasons for such an interface for `std::discrete_distribution`.

The problem is that such an interface allows only one reasonable implementation, known as ["roulette wheel selection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) (requires one call to random number generator and `O(log(N))` array lookups for binary search). Another algorithm, known as ["alias method"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method) (requires two calls to random number generator and one array lookup) can't be used to implement this interface (well, `probabilities()` can be implemented if we will store corresponding probabilities in a separate array, but it's sort of unfair and inefficient :), because alias method can't be used if we need to sample from subsequences.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @TimothyShields I'm asking why standard interface made in such a way that it doesn't allow more efficient implementation (`O(log(N))` vs `O(1)`).

Comment: Why not just use this? [Roulette-wheel selection via stochastic acceptance](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.3627v2.pdf) See section 3 especially.

Comment: @TimothyShields It doesn't provide guarantee of constant number of calls to RNG.

Comment: From the page on [`std::discrete_distribution::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/operator()): "Complexity: **Amortized** constant number of invocations of `g.operator()`." (emphasis added) Expected constant complexity is equivalent to amortized constant complexity in practice.

Comment: @TimothyShields, yep, missed that. But still, alias method guaranties two calls to RNG and only one lookup, it's obviously better.

Answer (score 2):

There are no requirements on the cost of constructing a parameters object for a given random distribution, nor on the nature of its internal representation. Or anything else. In particular, the parameters object does not have to be and often will not be just a vector of its construction parameters. Constructing the parameters object must perform whatever precomputation/preprocessing is necessary to make later generation of the distribution efficient. (That's not just true for `discrete_distribution`. There are many distributions for which the natural parameters require a precomputation step of non-trivial cost.)

In order to implement the "roulette-wheel" algorithm, the parameters object constructor would have to turn the arguments into a Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF). However, that parameters object would not be useful because, as you say, it has expected O(log n) execution time for each invocation, and the standard requires amortized O(1). The alternative stochastic algorithm could be used instead, which has stochastic O(1) time, which I suppose qualifies; it also requires an O(n) preprocessing step on the parameters in order to extract the maximum value.

The alias method, which seems to me to be optimal, requires a more complicated O(n) preprocessing step, but as I said earlier there are no requirements on the construction cost of the parameters object. (The size of the computed alias probabilities object is also O(n); the implementation I use rounds n up to a power of 2, so its worst-case size is less than 32n bytes. I haven't looked at any standard library implementation.)

The alias method does not require two PRNG calls, by the way. It's very common to implement it with one: given n possible outcomes, you divide the range of the PRNG into n discrete pieces (which is why I round n up to a power of 2); the threshold value for each piece is based on the original random number. If the division into discrete pieces was with the modulus operator, then the thresholds are proportional to the entire range of the possible random numbers; if the division is by range, then the thresholds are proportional to the size of the box and offset by the box's origin. Either way, the same random number is used both to select a box and then to select one of the two aliases, and the generation function consists roughly of:

```
auto r = prng();
size_t b = box_select(r);
return r > threshold[b] ? alias1[b] : alias2[b];
```

That is not just amortized O(1); it is O(1). So it meets all requirements.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if same random number `r` can be used for both box selection and threshold check. Because we are basically choosing a point in cartesian coordinates, where `x` coordinate is used to choose the box and `y` is used to choose one of two aliases.

Comment: @KostyaBazhanov: In the simplest theoretical description of the algorithm, you need two random variates, on in the range [0, Nbox) and the other in the range [0, ΣWeight). In all the practical implementations I've seen (or written), one random variate is used, effectively from the range [0, LCM(Nbox, ΣWeight)). If you can generate 64-bit random variates, then you can round the weights to 32 bits and increment N to the next power of 2. That lets you get both values from a single random number using only a bitmask. Because ΣWeight is not normally a power of 2, you occasionally have to reject...

Comment: a random variate, but with the constraints as above, and assuming the number of boxes is not in the millions, the rejection percentage is so small that it can be ignored for analytic purposes.

Comment: I'm interested in missions :) The difference between roulette wheel and alias method is hardly visible with smaller number of samples. Here is why (http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/) I'm talking about 2 calls to PRNG.

Comment: @KostyaBazhanov: I know what you're talking about. But you don't need two calls to the PRNG, honest. I've tried to explain how to do it; the only thing left is to actually paste code, which I might do if I get bored. But all the hints are there. :)